# ingress-nginx config use custom variables

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a `nginx conf` like below

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  access_log  off;
  return 200 'Hello, World! - nginx\n';
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(dev-)?(?<app>[^.]+)\.mysite\.com$;
  access_log  off;

  location / {
     resolver 127.0.0.11;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass http://${app}-web;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I expected that redirecting

`dev-blog.mysite.com` into service `blog-web`

`dev-market.mysite.com` into service `market-web`

and so on

Is there any way to implement this in k8s ingress-nginx?

Answer (score 2):

No, you would make a separate Ingress object for each (or one huge one, but that's less common). Usually this is semi-automated through either Helm charts or custom controllers.

Comment: You could write your own Ingress Controller to support this sure. But you can also just run Nginx with your own config in your own pod and ignore the Ingress system since it doesn't sound like that is what you want :)